# Naturality of Puppe sequence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

$\require{AMScd}$
On page 398 [Hatcher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_nsSIsv35AhWWraQKHVzIBhQQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpi.math.cornell.edu%2F%7Ehatcher%2FAT%2FAT.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2uCLe8pwJfnFPY3JGfePWO) states that the Puppe sequence has a naturality property, namely that a map $f \colon (X,A)\to (Y,B)$ of CW-pairs induces maps between the Puppe sequences of these pairs, with homotopy-commutative squares, i.e. the following diagram commutes up to homotopy:

\begin{CD}
A @>>> X @>>> X/A @>\varphi>> \Sigma A @>>> \Sigma X @>>> \Sigma(X/A) @>>> \Sigma^2A @>>> \cdots\\
@Vf|_AVV  @VfVV  @V\overline{f}VV  @V\Sigma(f|_A)VV  @V\Sigma(f)VV  @V\Sigma(\overline{f})VV  @V\Sigma^2(f|_A)VV  \\
B @>>> Y @>>> Y/B @>>\psi> \Sigma B @>>> \Sigma Y @>>> \Sigma(Y/B) @>>> \Sigma^2B @>>> \cdots\\
\end{CD}

Here $\Sigma X$ denotes the reduced suspension of $X$ and the map $\overline{f}$ is given by $\overline{f}([x]) = [f(x)]$.

I understand how Hatcher constructed the map $\varphi$ (and $\psi$ similarly), by defining it to be the composition
$$
X/A \to X \cup CA \hookrightarrow (X \cup CA) \cup CX \twoheadrightarrow SA \twoheadrightarrow \Sigma A,
$$
where the first of these maps is a homotopy inverse of the quotient map $X \cup CA \twoheadrightarrow X/A$ and $SA$ denotes the unreduced suspension. Moreover, I see that the first two squares in the diagram commute. I only fail to see why the third square commutes up to homotopy. I have tried showing by hand that $\Sigma(f|_A) \circ \varphi$ is homotopic to $\psi \circ \overline{f}$, but this hasn't led to anything, unfortunately.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the sequence
$$X \cup CA \hookrightarrow (X \cup CA) \cup CX \twoheadrightarrow SA \twoheadrightarrow \Sigma A
$$
is natural. Moreover the quotient map
$$p_{(X,A)} : X \cup CA \twoheadrightarrow X/A$$
is natural. In fact, if $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$, then $\bar f \circ p_{(X,A)} = p_{(Y,B)} \circ f'$, where $f' : C \cup CA \to Y \cup CB$ is the obvious map induced by $f$.

Letting $h_{(X,A)}$ and $h_{(Y,B)}$ be homotopy inverses for $p_{(X,A)}$ and $p_{(Y,B)}$, we get
$$h_{(Y,B)}  \circ \bar f \simeq h_{(Y,B)} \circ \bar f \circ p_{(X,A)} \circ h_{(X,A)} = h_{(Y,B)} \circ p_{(Y,B)} \circ f' \circ h_{(X,A)} \simeq  f' \circ h_{(X,A)} .$$
This shows that the third square commutes up to homotopy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what you mean by $p_{(Y,B)} \circ \overline{f} = f' \circ p_{(X,A)}$, since the domains don't even agree. Could you clarify a little?

Comment: @jasnee You are right. I corrected it.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for your help!